# rsync: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss

Tags: ssh, rsync

I get this error when using rsync:

```
$ rsync -av server:file .
Unable to negotiate with 10.1.1.50 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: [SO duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208495/unable-to-negotiate-with-xx-xxx-xx-xx-no-matching-host-key-type-found-their-of/34209177#34209177)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
$ rsync -av -e 'ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss' server:file .
```